# Finding bay window dimensions

Tags: geometry

I make CAD drawings of buildings.

Sometimes I need to draw a bay window and I end up with a geometry problem I can't solve easily and it slows down my work.

Here is a poor quality sketch of one of these problems:

[image: bay window plan view]

The whole window takes up $2125$ mm of wall length. Each of the sloped panes has half the length of the front pane. I need to draw the window from the front.

I know that $2a + 2b = 2125$, that $b^2 + 40^2 = a^2$, and even that for some angle, $\theta$, $$\sin\theta = \frac{b}{a}$$ $$\cos\theta = \frac{40}{a}$$ and $$\tan\theta = \frac{b}{40}$$
but I am not much good at algebra and I am not able to solve any of these equations :(

How should I approach this type of problem? Can it be solved or do I need more measurements?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks a million! It was well worth asking the question just to learn that ^_^

Comment: It doesn't cornern math, but is that 40 supposed to be 40mm or 40cm? If it's 40mm, then this bay window is very shallow, compared to how wide it is.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński it's 40mm. Yes, it's kind of a fake bay window I guess. But in my experience there is no standard for this angle - I draw many bay windows and they come in all shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two unknowns and two linearly independent equations, you can find the unknowns. Here, two equations are

$$2a+2b = 2125\ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
$$b^2+1600=a^2\ \ \ \ \ \ \  (2)$$

Now, what you should know is that we have $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$. From $(1)$, we have $a+b = 1062.5$. And $(2)$ gives $a^2-b^2 = 1600 \implies (a+b)(a-b) = 1600$. From here, you can find $a-b$ and then solving it by knowing $a+b$ is easy.

Comment: Thanks so much for this insight. It will help me a lot in the future

Comment: You're welcome :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed you have $$b = \sqrt{a^2-40^2} $$
so $$ 2125 = 2a + 2 \sqrt{a^2-40^2} $$
to solve such equation, you move $2a$ to the left side and take a square of both sides:
$$ (2125-2a)^2 = 4(a^2-40^2)$$
$$ 2125^2 - 4\cdot 2125 a + 4a^2 = 4a^2- 4\cdot 40^2$$
$$ -4\cdot 2125 a = -2125^2 - 4\cdot 40^2$$
$$ a = \frac{2125^2 + 4\cdot 40^2}{4\cdot 2125} $$
from this you can find the rest of the dimensions easily.

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, but I kept going wrong. Thanks a lot for the demonstration.